# Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: linq

I want to import excel and before import to database it should show duplicate row. I have datatable and using linq I am trying to do this. but it is giving error Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'. in some cases Predecessor column may empty.

Need help. Thanx.

here is the code:

```cs
var duplicateValues = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
 let EventCode = row.Field<string>("Event Code")
 let Predecessor = (string)row["Predecessor"]

 let Successor = (string)row["Successor"]
 let RelType = row.Field<string>("Relation Type")
 group row by new { EventCode, Predecessor, Successor, RelType } into grp

 where grp.Count() > 1
 select new
 {
     grp.Key.EventCode,
     grp.Key.Predecessor,
     grp.Key.Successor,
     grp.Key.RelType
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Try this: `let Predecessor = row["Predecessor"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)row["Predecessor"];`. This does a check for `Predecessor` having a value before converting it to a string. If it is DBNull, then store null for the string.

Comment: it would be more clean:
```c#
(row["Predecessor"] ?? "").ToString()
```